# Changing pages URLs without using route controllers

Tags: javascript, html, url

First of all, sorry for the lame question (probably). I tried to search for an answer but I'm not finding everything I need for my issue.

So... I have a bootstrap website and I am trying to change the page URLS to appear like this :

For example : www.site.com/AboutUs.html - to appear as www.site.com/about-us

I am using the pushState method for this as it follows:

```
var stateObj = { AboutUs: "about-us" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "About Us", "about-us");
```

So I get the needed URL address there (www.site.com/about-us).. so far so good. But on page refresh it throws an error stating "The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server."
If I hit the back browser button it goes to www.site.com/AboutUs.html again.(and it is supposed to go on the home page)

My question is :

What am I missing, am I supposed to make a controller and how ?

I am not using C#, I can probably use some help with PHP because I am not good at it. JavaScript / jQuery are welcomed.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the dumb question.

Happy days!

Comment: Merely using pushState to change the URL doesn't really give you the benefits of using MVC. There are plenty of great tutorials out there to help you get started; or better yet, use a framework that already exists like Laravel, Symfony, CakePHP, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of `pushState` is to be able to say: *I have modified the page with JavaScript, the new state is what you would get if you just asked the server for this URL*.

You shouldn't use JavaScript for this problem at all. You just want to have a page appear at a particular URL.

You need to configure the server to serve up the content you want on the URL you want.

> What am I missing, am I supposed to make a controller and how ?

You need something on the server to handle the URL `/about-us`.

"A controller" is something you would probably use if you were using the MVC architecture on the server … and it doesn't sound like you are.

More likely you will be wanting to use an `Alias`, a tool like `mod_write`, or simply moving the static file to a directory called `about-us` and renaming it `index.html`.

Comment: Greetings and thanks for the answers guys.

I am not using asp .net mvc so yes, you are right. That's why I am asking how is it done without it. 

One more question - if I move the files to new directories would that affect the SEO ? 
And does this mean that I have to write new htaccess file for every single one of them? 

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: "am not using asp .net mvc" — MVC is a common design pattern that is not exclusinve to ASP.NET MVC, which is mearly a framework which uses that pattern.

Comment: "if I move the files to new directories would that affect the SEO" — See [this](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=changing+URLs+and+SEO)

Comment: "And does this mean that I have to write new htaccess file for every single one of them? " — See [the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html): *apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof*